# jquery drop down menu not working with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My slidedown function of jQuery is not working this is the jquery code

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
             $("ul.drop > li").hover(function(){
                $(this).find("ul.up").Toggle(550);
             })
            });
        </script>
```

And the html :

```
    <div id ="navMenu">
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Types</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Facts</a>
                <ul class="up">
                    <li><a href = "#">T1</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T2</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T3</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T4</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T5</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: please explain a bit further what you want to achieve with this. what should your code do exactly?

Comment: Must be `toggle(550)` instead of `Toggle(550)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one script tag to load jquery, then another to inline JS.

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.drop > li").hover(function(){
      $(this).find("ul.up").toggle(550);
    })
  });
</script>
```

Also, as @anu pointed out, its `.toggle()` with lowercase "t".

Comment: Also `Toggle` should be replaced with `toggle`

Comment: "inline JS" is JavaScript that is inline with HTML, as in: `<a onclick="javascript here">`. Script that is enclosed within `<script></script>` is "internal JavaScript".

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Placing_the_code#Inline_JavaScript

Comment: @C14L And we know Wikipedia never has incorrect information. In reality, when people say "inline", they mean that the code is in a line with other stuff. `<a onclick="javascript here">` is "inline" JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example,

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
         $("ul.drop > li").hover(function(){
         $("ul.up").toggle(1000);
       })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id ="navMenu">
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Facts</a>
                <ul class="up">
                    <li><a href = "#">T1</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T2</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T3</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T4</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T5</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">T6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```